# Fluid Sub-element 1px Too Wide, But Only In One Place

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/Yn7e7

For some reason the ".ep" div is 1 pixel too wide *only in the ".heading" container*, resulting in the header flowing to the next line. For dynamically generated content via php, which I put in the "#contents" div and has the same exact structure / uses the exact same CSS as the ".heading" div, it displays correctly. I've even validated my HTML/CSS with W3C. What gives?

For a more robust example refer to the project I'm working on found [here](http://colechrzan.com/tv_rewrite).

Code (for those who do not wish to click) found below.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container toolbar">
            <div class="search"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="container heading">
            <div class="sid"><p>Show ID</p></div>
            <div class="network"><p>Network</p></div>
            <div class="title"><p>Title</p></div>
            <div class="ep"><p>Episode</p></div>
        </div>
        <div id="contents">
            <div id="loading" style="display: none">
                <img src="assets/img/loading.gif" alt="loading" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}
.container p {
    margin: 0;
}
#contents {
    margin-top: 8em;
}
#contents #loading {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -8px 0 0 -8px;
}
.toolbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background: #ccc;
    color: #000;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 5em;
}
.toolbar > div {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.heading {
    position: fixed;
    top: 5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #00f;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
}
.heading > div {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.heading p {
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 3em;
}
.sid {
    width: 10%;
}
.network {
    width: 25%;
}
.title {
    width: 50%;
}
.ep {
    width: 15%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the inline-block on the headings children div's. inline-block displays the elements as inline yet preserves some positioning features of block level elements. This means that whitespace is treated as it is in inline elements, so the newline between each of your divs is rendered as a space and throwing your widths off.

Get rid of the white space or use a float instead of inline-block.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the spaces between your divs.

```
<div class="container heading"><div class="sid"><p>Show ID</p></div><div class="network"><p>Network</p></div><div class="title"><p>Title</p></div><div class="ep"><p>Episode</p></div></div>
```

or

```
<div class="container heading"><!--
    --><div class="sid"><p>Show ID</p></div><!--
    --><div class="network"><p>Network</p></div><!--
    --><div class="title"><p>Title</p></div><!--
    --><div class="ep"><p>Episode</p></div><!--
--></div>
```